# Can I use the new Windows 11 UI styles (dark mode, titlebar, etc) from a Winforms application?

Tags: windows, winforms

Microsoft has their new Windows 11 approach to styling that features a color scheme, new title bar, side navigation, font and widgets design

[image]

I am trying to create a desktop application that embraces their new vision for UI decorations.

I am familiar with Winforms and a little familiar with WPF and started a project using the default Winforms template.

Out of the box the default app does not seem to use the new Windows 11 styles. While it does bare some resemblance, it doesn't respect the system colour scheme, etc.

[image]

I have been looking for documentation on their new approach to styling - looking at style best practices and that sort of thing but it's quite difficult to discover.

Am I going down the right path to make modern Windows UIs? I saw they had something new called WinUI - is that where my focus should be?

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/maui